# Ruby on Rails runs extremely slowly (5-10 minutes per command)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have begun teaching myself Rails with http://ruby.railstutorial.org. I have set up an environment using Railsdownloader, with gitbash and vim in windows

It seems to me the commands react too slowly. almost any command takes 3-10 minutes. a NEW, SERVER or SCAFFOLD command can take 15 minutes to process.

I have tried searching for such problems. It says everywhere that Ruby at large, and Rails especially is slow, but it seems completely unreasonable and I haven't seen evidence for other peoples Rails working THAT slow on building rails apps.

I am running it on a not-state-of-the-art computer but not a terrible one either. Moreso Rails does not take all the computing power available.

I would be very glad if someone can help me solve this (or say its normal, Rails takes for ever) thank you very much, Ari

thanks for the comments, update:
I got my background down to almost 0 (4%cpu) (out of i3 2*2.4GHZ 3 GB catch)
The command Rails new sample took 1:04 minutes using ~50% CPU on avarege.
The command Rails S, inside sample took 5:14 minutes using~60% CPU on avarege (that is until localhost shows the standard welcome page) this is with a completely empty app, with only defaults and nothing running in the background.

anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: Obviously it should not be that slow. Is this on a fresh app? If not see if the commands are just as slow on a new app.

Comment: It seems likely that you have a different process running. Can you check your process monitor to see if the CPU is running at 100%?

Comment: Definitely should not be so slow. I am running rails on a linux machine, but in a fresh app you should not wait longer that a few seconds for any rake task. It may get longer when your app grows bigger with a lot of models and dependencies, but never to the grade of minutes!!! I am running on a 6 years old Asus, 2x1.83GHz, 1GB RAM. This must be windows related.

Comment: I got my background down to almost 0 (4%cpu) (out of i3 2*2.4GHZ 3 GB catch)

The command Rails new sample took 1:04 minutes using ~50% CPU on avarege
The command Rails S, inside sample took 5:14 minutes using~60% CPU on avarege (that is until localhost shows the standard welcome page)

this is with a completely empty app, with only default creation.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 3.2.X?  I think there was supposed to be significant initialization speedups with the newest versions.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 Rails I tried 3.2.3, 3.2.4.rc1, in both I have the same problem.

Comment: You may want to look at this.  You may also have a slow hard drive, which will be an issue as you are creating files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529852/why-do-people-say-that-ruby-is-slow

Comment: You may find this comparison of ruby on windows vs linux to be useful: http://programmingzen.com/2009/08/10/how-much-faster-is-ruby-on-linux/

Comment: Definitely something wrong with your environment. Our massive production Rails app with 30 gems takes 3 minutes to bootstrap on my 2008 netbook's  Atom processor which is assuredly much, much weaker than your computer.

Answer (score 0):

RoR (3.2.9) on windows is incredibly slow. Linux virtual machines on Windows host is just as slow.

The only way to develop RoR is on a Linux standalone machine. My condolences for those who struggled with the problems.